# Calculate statistics of raster based on plygon borders in google earth engine

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, statistics, mosaic

I have a script in GEE that takes shepfile (sometimes with two polygons), classify it to 3 different classes and create one new layer with those 3 classes.
I want to calculte statistic for each polygon with the number of pixels that beling to each class.
I have  a code for this:

```
 var stats = function(ndviClassImg){

  var num_pos=ndviClassImg.gt(2).selfMask().reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: geometry,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    //maxPixels:1310361348,
    scale: 20  
  }).values().get(0);

    var num_neg=ndviClassImg.lt(2).selfMask().reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: geometry,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    //maxPixels:1310361348,
    scale: 20  
  }).values().get(0);

    var num_mean=ndviClassImg.eq(2).selfMask().reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
    geometry: geometry,
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    //maxPixels:1310361348,
    scale: 20  
  }).values().get(0);


  return ndviClassImg.set('num_pos', num_pos).set('num_neg', num_neg).set('num_mean', num_mean);

};
```

but when I print the image or the geometry I don't get this data about how many pixels I have in each class.

**My end goal: to get the data for each polygon about how many pixels I have in each class (I want also to do more calculation with this later on)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ee.Reducer.count().group()`. It do require a second band with the 'groups', like this:

```
function count(geometry) {
  var groups = ee.List(
      ndviClassImg.addBands(ndviClassImg) // Add a second band for the groups
        .reduceRegion({
          reducer: ee.Reducer.count().group(),
          geometry: geometry,
          scale: 30
        }).get('groups')
  )
  return ee.Dictionary.fromLists(
    groups.map(function (dict) { return ee.String(ee.Dictionary(dict).get('group')) }),
    groups.map(function (dict) { return ee.Dictionary(dict).get('count') })
  )
}

var counts = geometry.geometries().map(count)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4488c75bd5636f4367ffbcb9460ddad4

Comment: is the number of added keys to the dictioanry is limited to 3? I have tried to add one more but couldn't

Comment: No, it’s the values of your classes

Comment: if I want to add one that will tell how many pixels we have in total? I have tried to add and set one that the condition was gt(0) and also lt(4) but it keeps add only 3 keys without tthe new one

Comment: In total - do you mean for all classes, or for all geometries?

Comment: for each polygon in the layer, number of pixels

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/149a084cf073903cab884eef09ef9074

Comment: it works. Do you know why the way I did didn't work? and why there was a need to put it at the beginning?

Comment: Your stats function work fine, you just never invoked it. https://code.earthengine.google.com/b37b365faa5cbdf6372fc07a04c71092

Comment: it seems like it doesn't add the total without this :   var totalCount = countByClass.values().reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())
  return countByClass.set('total', totalCount)
}

Comment: is there any way I can now calculte things inside this dictionary? for example if I want for each polygon to calculate the ratio between the two values of two keys or to multiply by 2 the result